# google function: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to use Google cloud function to transcode videos from a storage bucket and outputs into another bucket using code posted online but with a few adjustments.

but I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined at transcodeVideo
>   (/srv/index.js:17:56) at /worker/worker.js:825:24 at  at
>   process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)

**Index.js**

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const projectId = 'cc18-223318';
const storage = new Storage({
    projectId: projectId,
});
const ffmpegPath = require('@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg').path;
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');

const transcodedBucket = storage.bucket('2400p');
const uploadBucket = storage.bucket('inpuut');
ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath);

exports.transcodeVideo = function transcodeVideo(event, callback) {
  const file = event.data;
  // Ensure that you only proceed if the file is newly created, and exists.
  if (file.metageneration !== '1' || file.resourceState !== 'exists') {
    callback();
    return;
  }

  // Open write stream to new bucket, modify the filename as needed.
  const remoteWriteStream = transcodedBucket.file(file.name.replace('.webm', '.mp4'))
    .createWriteStream({
      metadata: {
        metadata: file.metadata, // You may not need this, my uploads have associated metadata
        contentType: 'video/mp4', // This could be whatever else you are transcoding to
      },
    });

  // Open read stream to our uploaded file
  const remoteReadStream = uploadBucket.file(file.name).createReadStream();

  // Transcode
  ffmpeg()
    .input(remoteReadStream)
    .outputOptions('-c:v libx264') // Change these options to whatever suits your needs
    .outputOptions('-c:a copy')
    .outputOptions('-vf "scale=4800:2400"')
    .outputOptions('-b:a 160k')
    .outputOptions('-b:a 160k')
    .outputOptions('-x264-params mvrange=511')
    .outputOptions('-f mp4')
    .outputOptions('-preset slow')
    .outputOptions('-movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov')
    .outputOptions('-crf 18')
    // https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg/issues/346#issuecomment-67299526 
    .on('start', (cmdLine) => {
      console.log('Started ffmpeg with command:', cmdLine);
    })
    .on('end', () => {
      console.log('Successfully re-encoded video.');
      callback();
    })
    .on('error', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
      console.error('An error occured during encoding', err.message);
      console.error('stdout:', stdout);
      console.error('stderr:', stderr);
      callback(err);
    })
    .pipe(remoteWriteStream, { end: true }); // end: true, emit end event when readable stream ends
};
```

Comment: Can you try to delete line "const projectId = 'cc18-223318';" and leave just "const storage = new Storage();", since projectId is optional field?

Comment: still same error

Comment: Then check the names of “transcodedBucket” and “uploadBucket”. “transcodedBucket” should be created and “uploadBucket” should have the same as the triggered bucket.

Comment: Everything as it should be as it is triggering correctly but execution interrupts with the mentioned error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that function transcodeVideo is using parameters (event, callback) to get file data. These parameters (event and callback) used for Node.js 6 according to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage#functions-calling-storage-node6), for [Node.js 8/10](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage#functions-calling-storage-node8-10) you should use (data and context). Please check the Node.js version with command `node -v`, or just checking it in Cloud Function section in Console.
The solution is to install old Node.js 6 version or edit your code compatible with Node.js 8/10.

Comment: well, I replaced the outdated code as you said and now the function executes "ok" in under 5ms with no output file, so I tried to delete code line 13 which checks if a file is newly created and now when I upload a new file the function the function starts with "Started ffmpeg with command:.." and after 60 seconds gives a timeout "Function execution took 60002 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'"

Comment: @Juggernaught In this case try to increase timeout [1], since function works more that the default 1 minute value. [1]: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#timeout

Comment: that got it working until running into another problem "memory limits exceeded" as it turns out the limit is 2GB for google functions which is not enough for converting 5K videos plus the maximum execution time for a function is 9 min which is also not enough, so I guess it's a dead end for this function.
really thankful any way :)

Comment: @Juggernaught no problem, you can upvote or accept my answer to help other members to find right answer